# Working with AJAX, PHP and MYSQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, checkbox

In the most simplest term, below is what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Its based on this example (they use one select instead multiple checkboxes form):
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

Where the item being populated is based on the checkbox selected, where if the user select a duration of four and the sub category of the course to be in sql, than only those courses where duration is four and under sql sub category will be populated.

My problem is the followings:
I want to be able to post multiple variable in the URL because as of now only one variable can be posted, and I get an error for the one not selected.

I want to be able to select multiple checkboxes at once. At its current state you can select multiple checkboxes but the results is only adjusted on the last checkboxes. FOr instance if checkbox 2 + 3 is check only 3 will be displayed, when I would want the result of 2 and 3.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function showUser() {
                var selectedPerson = $('#testform').serialize();
                                                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "<div class='loading-indication'><img src='ajax-loader.gif' /> &nbsp; Please wait... Loading New Courses...</div>";


                $.ajax({
                    url:'getuser.php',
                    type:'post',
                    data:selectedPerson,
                    success:function(res){
                        $('#txtHint').html(res);
                    }
                })
            }
        </script>

        <script>
            function showUser2() {
                var selectedPerson = $('#testform2').serialize();
                                                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "<div class='loading-indication'><img src='ajax-loader.gif' /> &nbsp; Please wait... Loading New Courses...</div>";


                $.ajax({
                    url:'getuser.php',
                    type:'post',
                    data:selectedPerson,
                    success:function(res){
                        $('#txtHint').html(res);
                    }
                })
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form id="testform">
            <input onchange="showUser();" name="person[]" type="checkbox" value="1">One<br>
            <input onchange="showUser();" name="person[]" type="checkbox" value="2">Two<br>
            <input onchange="showUser();" name="person[]" type="checkbox" value="3">Three<br>
            <input onchange="showUser();" name="person[]" type="checkbox" value="4">Four<br>
            <input onchange="showUser();" name="person[]" type="checkbox" value="5">Five<br>
        </form>

        <form id="testform2">
            <input onchange="showUser2();" name="person2[]" type="checkbox" value="communication">communication<br>
            <input onchange="showUser2();" name="person2[]" type="checkbox" value="business">business<br>
            <input onchange="showUser2();" name="person2[]" type="checkbox" value="html and css">Three<br>
            <input onchange="showUser2();" name="person2[]" type="checkbox" value="sql">Four<br>
            <input onchange="showUser2();" name="person2[]" type="checkbox" value="windows">Five<br>
                      <input onchange="showUser2();" name="person2[]" type="checkbox" value="cloud">Cloud<br>
            <input onchange="showUser2();" name="person2[]" type="checkbox" value="microsoft office">Java<br>

        </form>

        <br>
        <div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here...</b></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

below is the php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}

th {text-align: left;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
 $person = '';
        $person  = isset($_POST['person']) ? $_POST['person'] : '';
        $allIds = '';
        if($person!=''){
            foreach($person as $personid){
                $allIds .= $personid.',';
            }
$allIds = rtrim($allIds,',');        }


 $person2 = '';
        $person2  = isset($_POST['person2']) ? $_POST['person2'] : '';
        $allIds2 = '';
        if($person2!=''){
            foreach($person2 as $personid2){
                $allIds2 .= $personid2.',';
            }
$allIds2 = rtrim($allIds2,',');        }


include("includes/db.php"); 



global $con;


$sql= "SELECT * FROM courses WHERE (course_duration IN ('" . $personid . "')) OR (course_duration IN ('" . $personid2. "')) LIMIT 10";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$sqlCount = "SELECT * FROM courses WHERE (course_duration IN ('" . $personid . "')) OR (course_subc1 IN ('" . $personid2. "')) OR (course_subc3 IN ('" . $personid2. "')) OR (course_subc1 IN ('" . $personid2. "')) OR (course_subc4 IN ('" . $personid2. "')) OR (course_subc5 IN ('" . $personid2. "'))";
$get_crs_count = mysqli_query($con, $sqlCount);
$count_rows = mysqli_num_rows($get_crs_count);
echo '<p style="margin-bottom: 8px;margin-top: 8px;font-size:18px;"><b>Number of courses available: </b>' . $count_rows ;
while($row_crs = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 

    $crs_id = $row_crs['course_id'];
        $crs_cat = $row_crs['course_cat'];

    $crs_provider = $row_crs['course_provider'];

    $crs_title = $row_crs['course_title'];
        $crs_price = $row_crs['course_price'];
          $crs_city= $row_crs['course_city'];
                      $crs_category= $row_crs['course_cat1'];

          $crs_date= $row_crs['course_date1'];


$crs_sdesc= $row_crs['course_sdesc'];
$crs_shortdesc = mb_strimwidth("$crs_sdesc",0,140,"...");
        $crs_image = $row_crs['course_image'];
        $provider_image = $row_crs['provider_image'];


  echo " <article class='search-result row'><center>
      <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3' id='thumbnailContainer'>
        <a href='#' title='Lorem ipsum' class='thumbnail' id='resultThumbnail'><img src='$provider_image' /></a>
     <a href='searchPage.php?crs_price=$crs_price' style='color:black;'>  <button id='resultprice'><span id='resultpriceText'>$ $crs_price</span></button></a>
      </div>
      <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2'>
        <ul class='meta-search' id='listDesign'>
        <a href='searchPage.php?crs_date=$crs_date' style='color:white;'>   <li><button id='resultInfo'><i class='fa fa-calendar fa-1x'><span id='iconText'>  $crs_date</span></i></button></li></a>
         <a href='searchPage.php?crs_category=$crs_category' style='color:white;'>   <li><button id='resultInfo2'><i class='fa fa fa-tags fa-1x'><span id='iconText'> $crs_category</span></i></button></li></a>
<a href='searchPage.php?crs_provider=$crs_provider' style='color:white;'><li><button id='resultInfo'><i class='fa fa-graduation-cap fa-1x'><span id='iconText'>  $crs_provider</span></i></button></li></a>
<a href='searchPage.php?city=$crs_city' style='color:white;'><li><button id='resultInfo'><i class='fa fa-map-marker fa-1x'><span id='iconText'> $crs_city</span></i></button></li></a>
        </ul>
      </div></center>
      <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-7 excerpet'>
        <h3 id='resultHeading'><a href='coursePage.php?crs_id=$crs_id' id='headingLinking'><b>$crs_title</b></a></h3>

        <div id='courseshortDescription'>
$crs_shortdesc
 <center><a href='coursePage.php?crs_id=$crs_id' style='color:white;'><button class='btn btn-danger' id='findoutBtn'>Find Out More</button></a> </center>
        </div>  

</div>

      <span class='clearfix borda'></span>
    </article>";
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is (mostly) in HTML code.

`<input type="checkbox">` does **not** use square brackets for name (in comparison to select - where there it causes that multiple select will be available).

Rewrite these two parts of your code

```
<input onchange="showUser();" name="person[]" type="checkbox" value="1">One<br>
<input onchange="showUser();" name="person[]" type="checkbox" value="2">Two<br>
<input onchange="showUser();" name="person[]" type="checkbox" value="3">Three<br>
<input onchange="showUser();" name="person[]" type="checkbox" value="4">Four<br>
<input onchange="showUser();" name="person[]" type="checkbox" value="5">Five<br>

<input onchange="showUser2();" name="person2[]" type="checkbox" value="communication">communication<br>
<input onchange="showUser2();" name="person2[]" type="checkbox" value="business">business<br>
<input onchange="showUser2();" name="person2[]" type="checkbox" value="html and css">Three<br>
<input onchange="showUser2();" name="person2[]" type="checkbox" value="sql">Four<br>
<input onchange="showUser2();" name="person2[]" type="checkbox" value="windows">Five<br>
<input onchange="showUser2();" name="person2[]" type="checkbox" value="cloud">Cloud<br>
<input onchange="showUser2();" name="person2[]" type="checkbox" value="microsoft office">Java<br>
```

into

```
<input onchange="showUser();" name="person" type="checkbox" value="1">One<br>
<input onchange="showUser();" name="person" type="checkbox" value="2">Two<br>
<input onchange="showUser();" name="person" type="checkbox" value="3">Three<br>
<input onchange="showUser();" name="person" type="checkbox" value="4">Four<br>
<input onchange="showUser();" name="person" type="checkbox" value="5">Five<br>

<input onchange="showUser2();" name="person2" type="checkbox" value="communication">communication<br>
<input onchange="showUser2();" name="person2" type="checkbox" value="business">business<br>
<input onchange="showUser2();" name="person2" type="checkbox" value="html and css">Three<br>
<input onchange="showUser2();" name="person2" type="checkbox" value="sql">Four<br>
<input onchange="showUser2();" name="person2" type="checkbox" value="windows">Five<br>
<input onchange="showUser2();" name="person2" type="checkbox" value="cloud">Cloud<br>
<input onchange="showUser2();" name="person2" type="checkbox" value="microsoft office">Java<br>
```

**EDIT**:
Part 2 (PHP):

use **unserialize** to value that PHP accepts from JavaScript - to get array of checked *options* - because you get a string, not an array

And also, for sticking of array items into string by *comma* ( *,* ) you may use function implode. And by the way, in this case you don't need to pre-set variables `$person` and `$person2`. So, I deleted that the first setting with empty value.

So, here it is corrected - and now this part should run

```
$person  = isset($_POST['person']) ? $_POST['person'] : '';
$allIds = '';
if($person!='')
{
    $person = unserialize($person);
    $allIds = implode(',', $person);
}

$person2  = isset($_POST['person2']) ? $_POST['person2'] : '';
$allIds2 = '';
if($person2!='')
{
    $person2 = unserialize($person2);
    $allIds2 = implode(',', $person2);        
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but then on the php page i get the following error:Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in  on this line              foreach($person as $personid){

Comment: sorry but this doesnt fix the problem

Comment: Added corrected PHP code - and also, inside code of sql you have wrong variable - use `$allIds` and `$allIds2` instead `$personid` and `$personid2`

Comment: hi thank you for the adjustment you made. I know get the following error: Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 1 bytes in and Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in these lines   $person = unserialize($person);
    $allIds = implode(',', $person);

Comment: So, what was dump report of GET with original code?